# How to replace a file in Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to rewrite the contents of a file by making a temporary file, manipulating the text, and then deleting the original to replace it with the temp. Here is the method:

```
private void deleteLine(String lineToRemove){
    File inputFile = new File("./src/class1.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("./src/tempFile.txt");

    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

    BufferedWriter writer;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!currentLine.trim().equals(lineToRemove)){
            writer.write(currentLine +     System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    System.out.println("Input to temp1: " + tempFile.renameTo(inputFile));
}
```

When testing this method, I found that everything works as intended except for the last two lines, which both return false. My class1.txt file exists when the method starts, but tempFile.txt does not.

Comment: Why do you use two files? You can just replace the string (lineToRemove) with empty string ("")

Comment: Do you have enough permissions on "./src/class1.txt" file? Mostly, system fails to override the file due to lack of write permission.

Comment: Yes, I do have enough permissions. As I said, I can write to the file, but the delete and replace functions return false.

Answer (score 3):

Below code work like a charm:

```
private static void copyFiles(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.move(source.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tempFile.txt` is there but you don't see it :), try refreshing your project (I assume you are using eclipse).

`Right click` on project folder > `Refresh`

you will see the file.

also you need a `inputFile.delete();` call

```
writer.close();
reader.close();

inputFile.delete();

System.out.println("Input to temp1: " + tempFile.renameTo(inputFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), [Streams](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/03/25/java8-examples-string-number-math-files/) and [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), which has some [benefits](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/nio-139333.html):

```
Path inputPath = Paths.get("foo.txt");
Path outputPath = Paths.get("foo.txt.tmp");
try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(inputPath);
     BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputPath)) {
     lineStream
        .filter(line -> !"pattern".equals(line.trim()))
        .forEach(line -> {
           try {
              writer.append(line);
              writer.newLine();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
           }
        });
}
Files.delete(inputPath);
Files.move(outputPath, inputPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

using apache commons io for java copy/replace file operation

```java
private static void copyFileUsingApacheCommonsIO(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
}
```